# Incorrect hyperlinking in LaTeX

Tags: latex, report, hyperlink, pdflatex, hyperref

So far the `hyperref` package in LaTeX has automatically linked all the items in my report correctly. But there is one that did not get linked properly, possibly because I manually added it to the table of contents like this:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the `\phantomsection` macro just before or after the `\addtocontentsline`. This instructs `hyperref` to add an anchor at that point. Also, take into account that you have to run LaTeX several times to make this anchor to be in the exact place.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a standard LaTeX document class, such as `report`, you can use the [tocbibind](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocbibind/) package, and then you won't need the `\addcontentsline` command and the hyperlinks should work correctly. From the documentation:

> The `tocbibind` package enables the titles of the Table of Contents, the List of Figure, the List of Tables, the Bibliography and the Index all to be added to the Table of Contents.

I'd also suggest looking at the [memoir](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) class, which also solves this problem. It's intended to be a replacement for the standard `report` and `book` classes, and provides lots of options and commands for customisation.